# what should be the size of the buffer

Tags: c, android-ndk, streaming, buffer

I have implemented a UDP client-server. Server is a PC and client is my android device. I have a decoder in native c which decodes the encoded frames and displays it on the screen. Now i have to add the option of streaming in it.

The UDP client is in C and i'm able to receive the data from the server and dump it into a file. Now my task is, instead of dumping it into a file, i should add it to a buffer which can be given as an input to the decoder. So, now my query is **what should be the size of my buffer?** because the data received from the server can be of any size, So how do i fix my buffer size.

I thought:

I can make a linked list, as and how i receive the data i would add it as a node to the linked list. But the problem here is, right now the decoder takes an encoded file as an input ans so i have to replace this input file with my received data. Hence there should be a single buffer (in case of linked list i would have multiple buffers) equivalent to the size of the received file.

I kindly request the viewers to provide useful suggestions for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see any way round this except to change your encoder/decoder protocol so that it can handle single frame buffers.  It is unreasonable to expect a streaming video service from a protocol that requires the entire file before it can be decoded.

Comment: Hey i was thinking of implementing a circular Queue for a buffer. Any suggestions??

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/